# In Selenium Grid, Test execution getting hanged if the parallel instances of tests are more than the MaxInstances set on Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, grid

In my Selenium Grid settings, I have set Test execution of my test cases in parallel with the thread-count 3 but the maxInstances that can be created for a browser in Grid I have set it to 2. Now the 2 test cases get its browser instances and start execution but the 3rd test case gets in deadlock at the following statement-

```
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(ExecutionConfig.HUB_NODE_URL), capabilities);
```

Can anyone please suggest a workaround to solve this problem.

Comment: how many nodes? if only 1node with 2 instances there is no free instance and it pauses there till one test finished and an instance is available again

Comment: only single node, is there any way in test case to know that instance is not currently availalable?

Comment: Hi Nikunj, did you get through it? Even I'm facing same issue..I'm creating 2 nodes ( on 2 different VMs) when running in parallel one gets hanged ..